# Point of inflexion.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given a function,

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$$

Do we say that a point of inflexion exists at $x=2$? Because on either side, the concavity changes.

Comment: A point of inflection should lie on the graph of $f$, and the $x$ you have chosen is not in the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not defined for $x=2$ so there is not a point on his graph with $x=2$. So there is not an inflection point of the graph of the function.

So, the concavity can change also if there is not an inflection point!

Comment: I concur. I had the same thought, but my professor shouted me down in class. This was just to confirm my answer. Thanks for your time.